# How to change JTable or JScrollpane size to fit a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, layout-manager

First off sorry for the dutch names of the components. Right now I want to have a form with a jtable and a button below it. I have a few methods that fill the tableModel - that I haven't posted here. The problem is my JTable is inside a JPanel that's inside a JPanel with a Gridlayout but it won't change the size.
At the moment my table (or?) my jscrollpane don't fit the page so it's always too big - I'm not sure which one is the bad-guy-component here

```
public class OpleidingenView extends JFrame implements iView{
private OpleidingenController controller;
private JTable tblOpleidingen;
private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
private JButton btnGoBack;
private JPanel pnlFirstrow, pnlSecondrow,pnlAll,pnlPaneel;
private JScrollPane scroller;
public OpleidingenView(){
    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    tblOpleidingen = new JTable(tableModel);
    tblOpleidingen.setEnabled(false);

    scroller = new JScrollPane();
    scroller.setViewportView(tblOpleidingen);

    btnGoBack = new JButton("Vorige");
    pnlFirstrow = new JPanel();
    pnlSecondrow = new JPanel();
    pnlPaneel = new JPanel();
    pnlAll = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));

    pnlFirstrow.add(scroller);
    pnlSecondrow.add(btnGoBack);

    pnlAll.add(scroller);
    pnlAll.add(pnlSecondrow);

    pnlPaneel.add(pnlAll);
    add(pnlPaneel);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: you have to understand how LayoutManagers are working, no way around :-) Nesting - as you do - has its cons (many) and pros (few). Here it obscures the cause (which is the default FlowLayout of the panel the table's scrollPane is added to)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way I know to make a panel stretch with the window/JFrame size is to put it in the center of a BorderLayout.

Comment: OP: Yeah but I kinda have my entire application set in a gridlayout :/ every other component adjusts to the size of the panels..

Comment: Then you're giving us a small piece of the puzzle and asking us to solve the whole thing.  This is, I think, why a number of people here do not attempt answers to partial questions -- it isn't that we don't have an idea of what is wrong, but that we hate guessing and then being told WE'RE wrong when all we were trying to do is help.  We cannot solve a UI layout problem for a small piece of a frame, especially not with GridBag involved.  Good luck

Comment: *"Good luck"*  +1 to that, as well as the attempt at answering a partial question.  I typically add a 'post an SSCCE' comment then leave it up to the OP.  'Post an SSCCE, or do without my help.'  I suspect  there are a lot of other people who hold basically the same view.